# Why post about POP3 C# is deleted?

Tags: support, status-completed

The following question

[Reading Email using Pop3 in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383/reading-email-using-pop3-in-c-sharp)

is deleted.

**"This question was removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation"**

I don't understand why.

IMHO, the contents of that question was **very useful**.

Now, I cannot access it. Neither backup question.

Is it possible access to that question?

Comment: http://www.stackprinter.com/export?question=44383&service=stackoverflow ... if Robert hadn't undeleted  it just now ... :)

Comment: Miracle! Now, I can access to it